# JavaScript onclick not displaying on page

Tags: javascript

I want to display a form after clicking on a link. ON the same page.  Why is this code not working ?

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="forgot();" class="txtmenu">Click Here if you forgot your password</a>

<script type='text/javascript'>
function forgot()
{
  document.write("

<form action=\"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>\" method=\"post\" > 
<table width=\"300\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" align=\"center\">
  <tr>
    <td>Enter your email</td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" maxlength=\"40\" class=\"form-field\" ><input class=\"submit-button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"forgot\" value=\"SEND MY PASS\" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>

 ");  
}
</script>
```

Comment: Why would you ever use document.write to write an entire form like that, makes my eyes hurt, and ten unicorns just died!

Comment: after page load, `document.write` will overwrite the current `document`. You need to put it in a `div` or something overlayed over the current content

Comment: Alternatively, you could output the form with `style='display:none;'` then toggle that instead.

Comment: Note your string concatenation is broken too... double quotes within double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You must add an `\` symbol at all the end of lines in multiline string.

Like:

```
function forgot()
{
document.write("\
<form action=\"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>\" method=\"post\" >\
<table width=\"300\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" align=\"center\">\
  <tr>\
    <td>Enter your email</td>\
  </tr>\
   <tr>\
    <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" maxlength=\"40\" class=\"form-field\" ><input class=\"submit-button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"forgot\" value=\"SEND MY PASS\" /></td>\
  </tr>\
</table>\
</form>\
 ");  
}
```

Comment: @user3011784 I tried it [here](http://hqnetworks.pl/st_910.html) and it works. Mayby there is error other place in your code?

Answer (score 0):

It doesnt work because you can't split a string over multiple lines like that. While I wouldnt recommend doing it your way with the document.write, you can fix it by doing this:

```
function forgot()
{
  document.write(

"<form action=\"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>\" method=\"post\" > " +
"<table width=\"300\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\"" +
      "align=\"center\">" +
  "<tr>"+
    "<td>Enter your email</td>"+
  "</tr>"+
   "<tr>"+
    "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" maxlength=\"40\""+ "class=\"form-field\" ><input class=\"submit-button\" type=\"submit\""+ "name=\"forgot\" value=\"SEND MY PASS\" /></td>"+
  "</tr></table></form>"

 );  
}
```

It's ugly but if you're going to be using document.write then it doesnt really matter as much ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should not just document.write after document finished loading. It will not make you any good. You should have some id for the element and modify it later when some event happens.

For example you create a div where id="myDIV" and make it invisible and the onclick you just

```
var itisMyDiv = document.getElementById("myDIV");
itIsMyDiv.style.visibility = "visible";
```

or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You must add an `\` symbol at all the end of lines in multiline string or use string concatenation (see [here](http://davidwalsh.name/multiline-javascript-strings)).

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="forgot()" class="txtmenu">Click Here if you forgot your password</a>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    function forgot()
    {
    document.write("\
    <form action=\"<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>\" method=\"post\" >\
    <table width=\"300\" border=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" align=\"center\">\
      <tr>\
        <td>Enter your email</td>\
      </tr>\
       <tr>\
        <td><input type=\"text\" name=\"username\" maxlength=\"40\" class=\"form-field\" ><input class=\"submit-button\" type=\"submit\" name=\"forgot\" value=\"SEND MY PASS\" /></td>\
      </tr>\
    </table>\
    </form>\
     ");  
    }
</script>
```

Using `document.write()` is bad idea, because it will overwrite the whole document. A quick and better way is to have some `div`, assign an `id` attribute to that div, then in `forgot()` function retrive that div using `document.getElementById` and replace contents by assigning your string to `innerHTML` property.